# Add space between two buttons

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, padding, margin

I have a LinearLayout with two Buttons in it. The Buttons are touching eachother in the middle of the Layout, i want to add some space between them. They are horizontal orientated and i would like to have the left button on the very left of the layout and the right one at the very right.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/truthDialogButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/truthdialogbutton"
                android:text="truth" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dareDialogButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/daredialogbutton"
                android:text="truth"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I´ve tried different thing like, increasing the margin or the padding of the layout and buttons, but nothing really seems to work

Comment: Could you please share a image  of expected output ? and also the current output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` in both buttons and give a `Space` between these buttons. And as you want to place these buttons on the left and right sides of the screen, you should set the width of the LinearLayout to `match_parent`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/truthDialogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/truthdialogbutton"
        android:text="Truth" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dareDialogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/daredialogbutton"
        android:text="Dare"/>
</LinearLayout>
```